# Booting with nfs just prints some weird character

Tags: linux, nfs, wireshark, embedded-linux

**Problem**

I have an embedded system which I am unable to boot via NFS using an Embedded Linux Kernel Image and rootfs both placed on my laptop (which serves as the NFS server as well as a TFTP server).

**Useful Information**

My laptop's /etc/exports:

> /tftpboot/rootfs_arm-gnueabi
>   *(rw,sync,insecure_locks,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)

Linux image (myImage) path: /tftpboot/
Root file system (rootfs) path: /tftpboot/

TFTP server and NFS server IP : 10.3.70.116
My Embedded system IP:          10.3.70.181

Commands I use to restart my NFS and TFTP servers

sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart

**Details**
When I start by embedded machine, U-Boot boots up and then system starts loading 'myImage' and finally it tries to access the rootfs via NFS while printing some weird characters as shown in the end of following quote.

> Filename 'myImage'.
>
> Load address: 0x2000000
>
> Loading:
>   *#################################################################################################################
>   done
>
> Bytes transferred = 1181188 (120604
>   hex)
>
> Booting image at 02000000 ...
>
> Image Name:   Linux-2.6.22.18
>
> Created:      2010-12-07   6:01:19
>   UTC
>
> Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel
>   Image (uncompressed)
>
> Data Size:    1181124 Bytes =  1.1
>   MB
>
> Load Address: 00008000
>
> Entry Point:  00008000
>
> Verifying Checksum ... OK
>
> OK
>
> Checking for Linux kernel endianess at
>   0x02000040 = 0xe1a00000
>
> Linux Kernel is LE
>
> Starting kernel in LE mode ...
>
> Uncompressing
>   Linux...............................................................................
>   done, booting the kernel.
>
> üààààüàààààüüààüüàü

I ran Wireshark and captured the packets to see what packets are going to and fro from the server and embedded machine. By doing so I found that at some point some NFSERR_NOENT error is appearing. and it seems as if the error arises while accessing/loading ld.so.preload

Following are some packets arranged as "Time Source Destination Protocol Info". Sorry for the jumbled view. I couldn't help it. :)

> 4776 20.482764   10.3.70.181
>   10.3.70.116           NFS      V2 LOOKUP Call (Reply In 4777),
>   DH:0xf4f053a1/etc
>
> 4777 20.482838   10.3.70.116
>   10.3.70.181           NFS      V2 LOOKUP Reply (Call In 4776),
>   FH:0x468d1c14
>
> 4778 20.483000   10.3.70.181
>   10.3.70.116           NFS      V2 LOOKUP Call (Reply In 4779),
>   DH:0x468d1c14/ld.so.preload
>
> 4779 20.483443   10.3.70.116
>   10.3.70.181           NFS      V2 LOOKUP Reply (Call In 4778)
>   Error:NFSERR_NOENT
>
> 4780 20.483712   10.3.70.181
>   10.3.70.116           NFS      V2 LOOKUP Call (Reply In 4781),
>   DH:0x468d1c14/ld.so.cache
>
> 4781 20.483839   10.3.70.116
>   10.3.70.181           NFS      V2 LOOKUP Reply (Call In 4780)
>   Error:NFSERR_NOENT

If you have read so far :) and got some clue, I will be delighted to know what you think is going wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the kernel is received, it is detected as OK but it crashes when run...
the kernel crash leads to the weird characters on the console, is the kernel file ok?